# Using node js Inside asp net mvc

Tags: node.js, express, asp.net-core, iis

I have an asp.net mvc Web Application in which I have a page related to upvc Window Design system, I have a react component about Unit designing which runs in node js, I want to host This component Inside that asp page without  using node js Web server
All answers are appreciated!

Comment: Title and body talk about **ASP.NET MVC** (which is on the full, classic .NET Framework - but the tag is `asp.net-core` - that's **not** the same! Which one is it now?? Please be **precise and accurate** in your descriptions of what systems you're using!

Comment: Can you describe the issue more detailed? I don't quite understand what this problem has to do with IIS. What kind of components do you want to host on IIS?